# Can't receive remote notifications GCM

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-cloud-messaging

I'm currently trying to receive **remote notifications** from a server while the app is in the foreground, at the moment it only works while the app is in the background and while I know this is by iOS design **is there any way I can implement push notifications to work both in the background and foreground?**

From reading a few questions in regards to this topic, I've noticed that *some* people have an issue of ***only*** being able to see their notifications in the foreground and ***not*** in the background. For some reason or another the exact opposite seems to be my issue.

Comment: There are two types of push, one that gets directed to the user, the other which gets directed to the app. Sounds like you don't know this, and you must presumably have implemented app-directed push (otherwise the app can't receive it in the background). A user directed push will be delivered to the app when in the foreground (and you turn it into a local notification) and will be delivered to the notification center when the app is in the background or terminated. This is what you are asking for.

Comment: I know the difference between a UILocalNotification and a push notification. Thanks.

Comment: I said "There are two types of *push*". I did not say "There are two types of notification". I'm talking about there being 2 different type of push notification. I suggest you go and read the Apple documentation or some more tutorials on push.

Comment: So is there a way for me to integrate push notification in the foreground or not? Because I've read quite a few questions pertaining to GCM and a few people have said that they got their remote notifications in the foreground and not the background. My problem is the exact opposite.

Comment: Yes. For a regular push if your app is not running or it is but it is in the background then the push is directly displayed to the user. If your app is in the foreground when the push is sent, it is delivered to the app, if you want the user to see it, you must display a local notification that looks identical to the push notification. As I already said "A user directed push will be delivered to the app when in the foreground (and you turn it into a local notification)"

Comment: I'd be interested in seeing some examples if you have any resources available. I know how to create a UILocalNotification, I'm just not exactly sure how to combine it with a push notification.

Comment: A method in your app delegate will get called when the push notification arrives (which ones are difference depending on if its iOS 10 or not) when your app is in the foreground. Just put your code to create the local notification there. You can extract the payload from the push notification and add it to the local notification.

Comment: There is CTCallCenter which can be used to get a callback of the call status (but you can't the number, only that a call is starting/ending etc.) However this only works if the app is in the foreground. In iOS 10 there is a new class CXCallObserver, I haven't used it so I can't say for definite but  it looks like its just the same as CTCallCenter, in which case the answer to your question is no.